# how to do post upload chunking(vs. download chunking)

Tags: html, playframework

So, in playframework, I can stream any response back so when i get a json request, I can do http chunking and stream the response back for some really really large responses.  I was wondering if the same can be done on POST calls.  If a client has a very very large POST call, can they stream me the request?  Is this possible with html?

That said, if I can't do that, i need an api that curl or some other non-browser client will use to upload a file(the json request, or a csv, etc).  How to create such an api?

I should note that I canNOT receive the whole request at once or will get out of memory.  I need to receive pieces and as I receive pieces put that to the backend datastore a piece at a time.

Also, what would be the curl syntax to make sure it is streaming the file rather than sending it in one huge huge request that would break the server?  How to force the client to stream the file in?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

You can get full control over HTTP request processing by using an [EssentialAction](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.EssentialAction). An EssentialAction processes the request body and returns a Result.

Normal Play [Action](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Action)s are a special case of EssentialAction. Actions process request bodies and return Results too, but they always perform their processing in two steps. Actions first parse the request body. Then the Actions parsethe parsed value to a function to get a Result. For you, having a separate parsing step is a problem because it means that the parsed value needs to be stored in memory.

If you use an EssentialAction then you can avoid storing a parsed value in memory, because you can just process the request body as it arrives.

What you need to do is add a method to your controller that returns an EssentialAction.

The signature of EssentialAction is:

```scala
trait EssentialAction extends (RequestHeader) ⇒ Iteratee[Array[Byte], SimpleResult]
```

The EssentialAction needs to accept the request header and then return an iteratee to process the request body. The iteratee will incrementally process the request body as it arrives. You can use your iteratee to put each piece into your data store as each piece arrives. When you're done processing all the pieces you can return a Result.

More info here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/HttpApi.